# How to export/store all paths in graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, bigdata, orientdb

I have a read-heavy graph with a million nodes and 100 million edges. My use case is to fetch all paths (depth 2, 3 and 4) paths between any two nodes. I tried doing this in Neo4j, OrientDB, and Postgres. Though it works in all three databases, I'm facing the following issues.

- Not very fast.
- Added slowness for supernodes.
- Unable to do pagination/sorting effectively.

One way to address all the issues is by pre-calculating all the paths. What is the best way to do this pre-calculation effectively and where store these paths? 
(Also, how to handle changes in the graph?)

Comment: In [graph terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory_terms),  "degree" refers to the *number of edges* (relationships) connected to a vertex (node). I presume you trying to find all paths that have a "depth" between 1 and 3?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. I have updated the post. Thanks.